# Any help for solving this system of partial derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let the following equation : $(x-z)\frac{∂u}{∂x} + (y-z)\frac{∂u}{∂y} + 2z\frac{∂u}{∂z} = 0$. We write the characteristic system(to reduce it to an ODE system) so : 
$\frac{dx}{x-z}$ = $\frac{dy}{y-z}$ = $\frac{dz}{2z}$.

And now how to continue from this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point you got, only two linear ODE remain to solve as shown below :

[image]